# How to setup Swift Mailer to send mails using SMTP server and TLS encryption?

Tags: 8, emails

I'm trying to send *Drupal 8* emails using *Swift Mailer* (5.4.8, 8.x-1.0-beta1) and a remote SMTP server. The transport should be encrypted, so TLS should be used. This is my setting:

[image]

**Unfortunatly when trying to send an email I'm getting a warning:**

> Warning: no valid certs found cafile stream: `/etc/apache2/ssl/certs/' in Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer->startTLS() [...]

And this error afterwards:

> Unable to connect with TLS encryption

Without the encryption I'm able to send mails using the remote STMP server.

A test of the connection using TLS from the server where Drupal is installed looks fine (I guess):

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.example.com:25 -starttls smtp
```

The response (excerpt):

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
[...]
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 4369 bytes and written 586 bytes
[...]
```

**So where do I get further details about the connection error? And what could be the cause of the problem?**

Comment: I'm not an expert on email, but are you sure `25` is the correct port?  On most mail hosts I've used, the encrypted port is `465`, and `25` is unencrypted.

Comment: You probably need to configure location of the cacert.pem via curl.cainfo = "C:\www\cacert.pem" and openssl.cafile = "C:\www\cacert.pem" in your php.ini if you are on localhost. Also even with this I had issues with ssl for abotu a year since something got broken in git for win(im on windows) so i always have to disable ssl validation. But if this is happening on server, something else is probably wrong.

Comment: Also you can download the file here https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Comment: @PatrickKenny: I'm pretty sure that the port should be `25`. I get an timeout error, when using port `465`.

Comment: @IvanJaros According to the watchdog log the valid cert should be in _/etc/apache2/ssl/certs/_. But although the pem-file has been downloaded to this directory and restarted apache, I still get the same warning and error.

Comment: I think in most cases the port 25 for Non-SSL Settings and 465 for Secure SSL/TLS Settings